# Reference request: The compactness and compact embedding in Besov Space?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded with smooth boundary. Let $0<s<1$, $1\leq p<\infty$, and $1\leq \theta\leq\infty$. We denote by $B^{s,p,\theta}(\Omega)$ the Besov space.  For definition of Besov space we refer to Leoni's [book](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-105), Chapter 14, section 14.1. (Also this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0120441438) by Adam, page 230, section 7.32.)

Theorem 14.29 in Leoni's book states the continuous imbedding theorem for Besov space. (For simplification, let's assume $p=1$.) We have $B^{s,1,\theta}(\Omega)$ continuous imbedded in $L^{\frac{N}{N-s}}(\Omega)$ for $1\leq \theta\leq \frac{N}{N-s}$.

We now take $r<\frac{N}{N-s}$.

My question is: do we have that $B^{s;1,\theta}(\Omega)$ is COMPACT imbedded in $L^{r}$? I think the answer is yes because according to this [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/245c-notes-4-sobolev-spaces/), exercise 15, that

> sequences bounded in a high regularity space, and constrained to lie
>   in a compact domain, will tend to have convergent subsequences in low
>   regularity spaces.

I would think my conjecture is true based on this fact. However, I did a deep search over the internet but has no lucky to find such result.

If there is no such result, please let me know (and maybe a counterexample?). If there is, please direct me to the reference.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into the book "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations" by Bahouri, Chemin, Danchin. In Section 2.9, Corollary 2.96 they prove that $B^{s,p,\infty}(K)$ is compactly embedded in $B^{s',p,1}(K)$ for $s'<s$ and compact $K$.